# how can I insert online video in word body using office js?

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-js, word-addins

I am trying to insert video in word document body but not succeed. is that possible to insert online video in word document using javascript. if anybody knows about it please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part didn't work?

Comment: hi @FreeSoftwareServers  is that possible to insert online video in word document using javascript or not , if possible then please give me an example thanks